# Data being lost in recors

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnNextStudent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextStudent.Click
        If txtExam1.Text > 100 Or txtExam2.Text > 100 Or txtExam1.Text < 0 Or txtExam2.Text < 0 Then
            MsgBox("You entered a mark higher than 100 or lower than 0. Please try again.",, "Input Error")
        Else
            ReDim StudentRecords(NumOfStudents + 1)
            btnFinished.Enabled = True
            StudentRecords(Index).StudentName = txtStudentName.Text
            StudentRecords(Index).Exam1Mark = txtExam1.Text
            StudentRecords(Index).Exam2Mark = txtExam2.Text
            MsgBox(StudentRecords(0).Exam2Mark)
            Index += 1
            NumOfStudents += 1
            txtStudentName.Clear()
            txtExam1.Clear()
            txtExam2.Clear()
```

This is the code I have right now and I'm trying to keep the data being entered in textboxes "txtStudentName", "txtExam1", and "txtExam2" in a record. The only problem is that the data is lost between each click of the button "btnNextStudent". I have no idea whatsoever what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused... `txtExam1.Clear()` clears the input in that textbox control... and it is run each time you click `btnNextStudent`. Is that what you mean by "the data is lost between each click..."?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is this:

StudentRecords(Index).StudentName is getting replaced again and again. You simply give it a new value. This is not possible in a string. If you want to keep track of multiple values, you should create a "List" containing your strings.

```
// Declare outside of button
Public StudentNameList As New List(Of String)()
Public Exam1MarkList As New List(Of String)()
Public Exam2MarkList As New List(Of String)()

// Add values when clicked
StudentNameList.Add(txtStudentName.Text)
Exam1MarkList(txtExam1.Text)
Exam2MarkList(txtExam2.Text)

// Retrieve values from your list
For Each Str As String In StudentNameList
    MessageBox.Show(str)
Next
```

I'm on a mac right now, so I can't assure you the code is correct. But that is the reason for your issue.